# laravel pdo_connection mssql

Tags: php, laravel

I have laravel 5.6 and I need to connect it to a mssql remote. I have the db_lib driver. I've installed the freetds. These are the messages:

```
PDOException  : SQLSTATE[IM001]: Driver does not support this function: driver does not support that attribute

at /home/agner/Documentos/ubuntu-laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:71

public function getServerVersion()
70|     {
 > 71|         return PDO::getAttribute(PDO::ATTR_SERVER_VERSION);
72|     }

Exception trace:

1   PDO::getAttribute()
      /home/agner/Documentos/ubuntu- laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/PDOConnection.php:71

2 Doctrine\DBAL\Driver\PDOConnection::getServerVersion()
/home/agner/Documentos/ubuntu-laravel/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Connection.php:496
```

Comment: But Laravel has supported sql server out of the box since Laravel 4, why do this yourself?

Comment: I'm using ubuntu 16, and in my project requirements, I have to use the pdo_dblib